# I'm new with API's. I'm working with rest API's in node js. I'm not getting how to go from one route to another?

Tags: node.js, routes, restful-url

In the example below, if I'm in localhost:5000/A and i want to go to localhost:5000/B, but from within localhost:5000/A, how can i do that via a button ?

var express = require('express');
    var app = express();

```
// Our first route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello Index!');
});

// Our A route
app.get('/A', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello A!');
});

// Our B route
app.get('/B', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello B!');
});

// Listen to port 5000
app.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('Dev app listening on port 5000!');
});
```

Comment: APIs are independent of UI and they are usually unaware of it. What are you trying to achieve, can you explain in more detail? Do you have a website which call this api? What does that look like? What do you mean by go from one route to another?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this :

```
app.get('/A', function (req, res) {
    res.send('Hello A! <button><a href="/B">Click me</a></button>');
});
```

Or you could serve an HTML page containing this code.

Hope this answers your question. If not please reach back to me.

Comment: I think this is simple enough to understand without any explanation but if you need more details just comment and I would be happy to help.